# NGINX - Rewrite version number in JS file name to parameter for PHP

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, nginx, versioning

I had a rewrite from `file.js?c=123` to `file.js.php?c=123` but query params were downgrading my SEO evaluation. Actually, some proxy CDN do not cache query params.

```
server {
    location ~ \startscript.js$ {
        rewrite (.*) $1.php last;
    }
}
```

SO, I would like to rewrite `file.123.js` to `file.js.php?c=123`. Is that possible?

Comment: "some proxy CDN do not cache query params" - was that something you _read_, or something you experienced? This shouldn't make any difference in terms of "SEO"?

Comment: @MrWhite my SEO has decreased after apply url to static with querystring. Actually, GTMetrix has warning related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> location ~ \startscript.js$ {
> ```

In regex the `\s` at the start of your *uri* is a shorthand character class that matches a single *space* (or "whitespace character"). So this is unlikely to have matched anything. However, you should backslash escape the literal dot before the file extension.

I assume "file" in `file.js` could be *any file*, it's not always "startscript"?

Try the following instead (**UPDATED**):

```
server {
    location ~ \.js$ {
        rewrite (.+)\.(\d+)\.js$ $1.js.php?c=$2 last;
    }
}
```

However, as I mentioned in comments, this makes no difference with regards to SEO (*search engines* handle the query string just fine - always have). In the past, it was possibly a *usability* issue, as some proxy servers did not cache based on the query string - so users might not have seen the correct content (if they were behind a proxy that behaved this way) - but this is *historical* AFAIK.

See also my answer to the following question:

- [Tradeoffs around using a query string vs embedding version number in the CSS/JS files](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86274/tradeoffs-around-using-a-query-string-vs-embedding-version-number-in-the-css-js)

---

> ... this is throwing 404 error, Eg: `domain.com/startscript.82b4527379bd2540f79f532950c7b96b.js`

The above example specifically matches digits only (as in your initial example). What you have there looks like a 32 char hex value (hash?). Try the following instead (**UPDATED**):

```
rewrite "(.+)\.([\da-f]{32})\.js$" $1.js.php?c=$2 last;
```

Or use the the more generic `\w+`, as @devnull suggested in comments, to match any "word" character (ie. `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z` and `_`). Although with regex, it's generally advisable to be as specific as possible, so if it's always a 32 char hex then match a 32 char hex.

Comment: Hmm, this is throwing 404 error, Eg: `domain.com/startscript.82b4527379bd2540f79f532950c7b96b.js`

Comment: @fiskolin, your question only showed integers. The example URL you just posted uses integers and letters. Try changing `(\d+)` to `(\w+)` in MrWhite's answer and that should match against the sample you just provided.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MrWhite, first match on location `location ~ \.js$ ` w/ `rewrite (.+)\.(\d+)\.js$ $1.php?c=$2 last;` isn't working (throwing 404 error). Second sol. `rewrite (.+)\.([\da-f]{32})\.js$ $1.php?c=$2 last;` is throwing an error on nginx conf file **nginx: [emerg] directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";"**. Tested on `nginx version: nginx/1.10.2`.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I'd missed the `.js` extension from the target URL. The seond solution also needs quotes around the regex, since it contains `}`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MrWhite `rewrite "(.+)\.([\da-f]{32})\.js$" $1.js.php?c=$2 last;` works, `rewrite (.+)\.(\d+)\.js$ $1.js.php?c=$2 last;` doesn't. I'll apply first, since rewrites only hash (md5) values.

Comment: As mentioned, the first rule should have worked for the example as stated in your question.